# How to draw a flowchart to calculate sum of all odd numbers between 1 to 100

Tags: c++, flowchart

Help me to draw flowchart to find sum of all odf no. from 1 to 100

Comment: [How to draw flowcharts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SWRDqTx8d4k).

Comment: If you have a problem with the algorithm think about how you would calculate this sum given a pen and piece of paper if someone was calling out numbers 1 by 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to keep track of this period and decide if every digit %2 leftovers then it is an odd number
, you can make a variable initialized by zero outside this loop, then you will use it inside the loop to sum all ood numbers produced from the if statement.

I suggest googling the problem on your own, it is more useful for you than my explanation